# Flatten array of arrays in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to flatten `string[][]` into `string[]`.

The advice given in dozens of SO answers is: `[].concat(...arrays)`.

But that gives me this error:

> Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray'.
>     Types of property 'slice' are incompatible.
>       Type '(start?: number | undefined, end?: number | undefined) => string[]' is not assignable to type '(start?: number | undefined, end?: number | undefined) => never[]'.
>         Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
>           Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Another way I tried is this:

```
let foo: string[][] = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]];
let bar = [].concat(...foo);
```

Which gives a similar error:

> Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray'.

Why does it work for everyone but me?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const a = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]
const result = a.reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator.concat(value), []);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This works without using the esnext library. Works for me on es2017. Best option for those who want to target wider range of browsers. Thanks!

Answer (score 48):

You can flatten the array with `flat()`

```
let foo: string[][] = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]];
let bar = foo.flat()
```

log

```
console.log(bar)   // a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c
```

UPDATE

By correcting the type to string[] you can also use `concat`

```
let foo: string[][] = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]];
let bar : string[] = []
bar = bar.concat(foo[0], foo[1], foo[2])
```

Comment: That gives me `Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'string[][]'`.
`

Comment: @lonix you need to add `esnext` to `libs` in tsconfig to make that work

Comment: Oh okay now that makes sense :-) But I excluded that for a reason, I'm not using anything bleeding edge till it's current. Would be nice to have that feature right now though!

Comment: I added an option to use concat, you have to specify the type of `bar` to be `string[]` and not `string[][]`

Comment: I think this is the best answer for those using the latest features, unfortunately for me I'll need to use the old for loop! :)

Comment: The concat option works without the latest features , you just need to set the correct type.

Comment: @lonix if you use typescript, you can always compile down to a lower version of javascript, so you can still use the latest features.

Answer (score 20):

Here's the simplest option:

```
let bar = ([] as string[]).concat(...foo);
```

Like @Kokodoko's approach but with the typings inline.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a generic solution:

```
function flatten<T>(arr: T[][]): T[] {
  return ([] as T[]).concat(...arr);
}
```

And a deep/recursive extension:

```
type NestedArray<T> = Array<NestedArray<T> | T>;

function flattenDeep<T>(input: NestedArray<T>): T[] {
  return flatten(input.map(x => Array.isArray(x) ? flattenDeep(x) : [x]));
};
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70313348/2482744) may be more efficient for a deep flatten, I just had fun trying to write something that felt more elegant to me.

Answer (score 10):

.flat() will also give the type error. 
You can use Generics to solve this

```js
let st : string[][] | Array<string> = [['a'] , ['b']]
    let bar = [].concat(...st);
    console.log(bar)
```

Either way, your call. Just know that your type declaration is not right.

Answer (score 6):

The code

```
const res = [].concat(...foo);
```

should work. I guess it's a misconfiguration in tsconfig that causes that error for you. Make sure that there is at least `es2015` (better `es2018`) in your tsconfig's `lib` array. To make the new `flat` work as shown by kokodoko, make sure to also add `esnext`

```
"lib": [
  "es2018",
  "dom",
  "esnext"
]
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe you have strictNullCheck: true

An empty array with no contextual type ([] in [].concat(arg)) is inferred as never[] under strictNullChecks. and never is not assignable from any other type.

([] as any[]).concat(foo); should do the trick

Answer (score 5):

For much more deeply nested array of arrays such as:
`[1, 2, 3, [4, [5, [6, [7]]]]]`

```
type NestedArray<T> = Array<NestedArray<T> | T>;

const flatten = <T>(input: NestedArray<T>, acc: T[] = []): T[] => {
  return input.reduce((_: T[], current) => {
    if (Array.isArray(current)) return flatten(current, acc);  
    acc.push(current);
    return acc;
  }, []);
};
```

Usage:

```
console.log(flatten([1, 2, 3, [4, [5, [6, [7]]]]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/678284/steven) worked for my jest tests but not in my actual angular 15 app due to a constraint error I can't figure out. Slightly modified as a regular recursive function to keep Typescript quiet :

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';

export type NestedArray<T> = Array<NestedArray<T> | T>;

export class ArrayHelper {
 
  public static flatten = <T>(input: NestedArray<T>, res: T[] = []): T[] => {
    input.forEach((el: T | NestedArray<T>) => {
      if (Array.isArray(el)) {
        ArrayHelper.flatten(el, res);
      } else {
        res.push(el);
      }
    });

    return res;
  };
}
```

Example tests:

```
 describe('flattening', () => {
      it('pass through', () => {
        expect(ArrayHelper.flatten(['hi', 'there'])).toHaveLength(2);
      });

      it('2 level', () => {
        expect(ArrayHelper.flatten(['hi', 'there', ['that', 'is', 'all', 'folks']])).toHaveLength(6);
      });

      it('as per SO', () => {
        expect(ArrayHelper.flatten([1, 2, 3, [4, [5, [6, [7]]]]])).toHaveLength(7);
      });

      
    });
```